# Print from mobile browser to bluetooth printer

Tags: printing, jquery-mobile, cordova, bluetooth, zebra-printers

Is there way to print from Apple and Android mobile browsers via bluetooth. I already searched a lot about this topic on whole internet but i did not find anything relevant.

My goal is that my web app (UI builded in jQuery mobile) can print to bluetooth mobile printer like  Zebra RW series... I know aware existence of Phonegap and Zebra SDK but is there simpler way to enable print page directly from Safari or Android browser.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, No. Android is more then capable of being able to connect to a RW via bluetooth. However, Apple in their infinite wisdom decided that if you wanted to be able to do bluetooth for something other then the media protocol, you needed to license their special implementation of bluetooth. So no printer can pair with an Apple device.

You are running into a hard(but interesting) problem. A browser doesn't have the ability to initiate communication to a bluetooth device directly.

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: since recently chrome has support for bluetooth communication and possibly also to serial print on a bluetooth printer: https://caniuse.com/#search=bluetooth

Comment: with iOS it might be possible to print something from within your app via bluetooth. you cannot print something via airprint or so. but you can connect to any bluetooth device and send data to the printer, the printer then prints the data...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Play - search for Datamax, and then download the version that is from Qualsoft.  It will print to any thermal printer that Datamax-Oneil currently supports.  It does some other interesting things with maps, etc... I know of no other utility that can printer from a browser other than Brother's use if Air Print / Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Check RawBT https://rawbt.ru/start.html you can create a button to send the data directly to mobile printer